# Simultaneous use of touch down and touch up gesture recognizers

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using two gesture recognizers on my `UIView`. One is standard `UITapGestureRecognizer`, another is very simple touch down recognizer I wrote:

```
@implementation TouchDownGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

@end
```

They work together only if I assign a delegate to both of them that contains this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

It's all working fine, but when I perform a long press on that view, touch down recognizer fires and touch up recognizer doesn't. For short taps everything is fine, they both fire.

I implemented all methods in `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to return YES to no avail. If I'm adding logging to see the interaction with delegate and inside my own recognizer, I can see that for both short and long taps the invocations sequence is identical — except for the call to touch up recognizer. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just check the touchUp directly from the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`?

```
-(void)selectionDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longPress
{
    if(longPress.state==1)
    {
       //long Press is being held down
    }
    else if(longPress.state==3)
    {
        //the touch has been picked up
    }
}
```

Comment: Great advice, thanks! That recognizer required `minimumPressDuration` to be set to 0 and now works fine